# Disable name demangling on GDB startup

Tags: c++, gdb

This may be a weird request, but is there a way to disable symbol demangling in GDB? Even better would be to disable name demangling for certian subset of symbols. I am dealing with some heavily templated code, and most of the time GDB spends demangling the symbols. Since they are gigantic/nonsensical, and are more compact when they are mangled, is there a way to turn this off?

Comment: How about `set print demangle off`? It is explained at https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_57.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately `set print demangle off` did not do anything, but `set demangle-style none` works! Saw it suggested here: https://github.com/capnproto/capnproto/issues/191

I put it in a `.gdbinit` file, and now I don't have to wait forever to set a breakpoint.

Answer (score 3):

gdb has a couple of settings to control demangling.  You can find them with `apropos demangle`, but basically the interesting ones are `set print demangle` and `set print asm-demangle`.

However, you should know that there's a [bug](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=12707) open because this setting was broken and never fixed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that it's a bug, because I tried that command and it didn't work. I thought I was crazy. I did find `set demangle-style none` though, which does work!